# Daisy-chain display port monitors on a MacBook Pro

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, displayport

According to this [WikiPedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_port#1.2) version 1.2 of the Display port specification allows for multiple monitors to be daisy-chained. My question has two parts:

1. Could this be done on a MacBook Pro 15" 2012 and what kind of equipment and monitor compliance is required?
2. Would it allow for
   separate desktops on each monitor, and how many monitors does it
   support?

Answer (score 1):

Only the new 15" Retina MacBook Pro's support multiple external displays.

Source (15" non-retina): http://www.apple.com/au/macbook-pro/specs/

Source (15" retina): http://www.apple.com/au/macbook-pro/specs-retina/